# Have UIButton showDetails take in an argument

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton, mkmapview

I have many UIButton elements on my MKMapView.  When the user clicks on a button I get a showDetails notification.  But how do I tell which button the user clicked on?  The only hack I know of is to pass in the tag value which is an integer.  Surely there must be a more elegant way.  I tried subclassing UIButton but since it is a cluster, I cannot subclass it and use all of theUIButtons existing functionality.

Thanks
Deshawn

Answer (score 0):

tag is a good way to identify you can also use current title to differentiate if all buttons have different titles. here is a code snippet

```
[[button currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"your desired string"];
```

But I prefer use tags.

Comment: So just use the tag as an integer index into some array?  No way to actually pass an opaque object?

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible through index or currentTitle.

Comment: Do you want an object according to button tapped out from array? if yes you need to use title then iterate through array of your objects and when you found the title's equal you got the object.